# Download a file programmatically on Android

Tags: android

I am downloading files from web server programmatically. After download is completed, I checked the file. The size ,extension and all other parameters are correct but when I try to play that file in media player it is showing that it is corrupted.

Here is my code:

```
    byte[] b = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    b = new byte[Integer.parseInt(size)];    // size of the file.
    in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);            
    in.read(b);
    in.close();

    File folder = new File("/sdcard", "folder");
   boolean check = folder.mkdirs();

   Log.d("HttpDownload", "check " + check);

   File myFile = new File("/sdcard/folder/" + name);


    myFile.createNewFile();
   OutputStream filoutputStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

   filoutputStream.write(b);

   filoutputStream.flush();

   filoutputStream.close();
```

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/921400/8460132

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is some working code I have for downloading a given URL to a given File object.  The File object (outputFile) has just been created using new File(path), I haven't called createNewFile or anything.

```
private static void downloadFile(String url, File outputFile) {
  try {
      URL u = new URL(url);
      URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
      int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

      DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
        stream.readFully(buffer);
        stream.close();

        DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
  } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
      return; // swallow a 404
  } catch (IOException e) {
      return; // swallow a 404
  }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to download a video from the same ??

Comment: This is for file downloading. You can download video files, sure. But if you mean streaming video, no, you want to use different APIs for that.

Comment: how can I create outputFile for passing?

Comment: Make sure to run this code on another thread without blocking the main thread.

Answer (score 12):

Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

Download Fuction Code

```
 public void downloadFile() {
        String DownloadUrl = audio1;
        DownloadManager.Request request1 = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(DownloadUrl));
        request1.setDescription("Sample Music File");   //appears the same in Notification bar while downloading
        request1.setTitle("File1.mp3");
        request1.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            request1.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request1.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
        }
        request1.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), "/File", "Question1.mp3");

        DownloadManager manager1 = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Objects.requireNonNull(manager1).enqueue(request1);
        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == 8) {
        DownloadSuccess(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the actual and best solution for download. By using this method your file will automatically handle by android system. This solution save my whole project.

Comment: Seems like a solid solution but, can you please elaborate size/bytes will it able to download?

Answer (score 5):

```
private void down(String string)
    {

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(URL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/load";
            Log.v("LOG_TAG", "PATH: " + PATH);

            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, option14[i].toString());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int len1 = 0;

            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }

            fos.close();
            is.close();

            Toast.makeText(this, " A new file is downloaded successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: this worked well for me! thank you. but can you please explain this line:  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; ? is it the maximum number of bytes allowed for the file?

Answer (score 2):

I checked [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525204/android-download-intent) but it looks like there is not a download Intent.

Did you try setting the [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) in the android manifest?

Answer (score 2):

1> Create an interface for the Handel download process

```
interface Downloader { fun downloadFile(url:String,fileSubPath:String):Long }
```

2> Create a class for handle download manager (In My case I created an AndroidDownloader class) and follow the process.

```
class AndroidDownloader(context: Context):Downloader {

private val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(DownloadManager::class.java)
override fun downloadFile(url: String,fileSubPath:String): Long {
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(url.toUri())
        .setMimeType("*/*")
        .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
        .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
        .setTitle("Downloading")
        .addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <token>") //Add this if token required for download file
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileSubPath)
    return downloadManager.enqueue(request)
} }
```

3> Now Create a BroadCastReciver class for monitoring the file download process.(In my case I created a DownloadCompleteReceiver class)

```
class DownloadCompleteReceiver:BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    if(intent?.action == "android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE") {
        val id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1L)
        if(id != -1L) {
            println("Download with ID $id finished!")
            context?.toast(context.resources.getString(R.string.text_file_download_successfully))
        }
    }
} }
```

4> Now Register Your BroadcastReceiver in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
        <receiver
        android:name=".utils.DownloadCompleteReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

5> Final Process Add The below line In your Activity or fragment where you want to download the file.

```
val downloader=AndroidDownloader(context)
    downloader.downloadFile(url,"total${Date().time}.$excitationPath")
```

Answer (score 1):

read on an input stream doesn't guarntee that the entire contents of the file will be pulled down in one go.  Check the return value on that in.read(b); line.  It might look something like this:

```
if(in.read(b) != size)
    Log.e("Network","Failed to read all data!");
```

That'll tell you, at the very least, if you're getting all your data from the networking layer.  If you only got a partial read, but you're still writing the full byte array to disk, that might explain why the media player thinks the file is corrupt.