# Integrate Dropbox in android app, but without login popup

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to use the dropbox in my application.I developed a sample application for upload and download files and it ask for authentication.

But I don't want to open login popup.

Is it possible access the dropbox by other users using default account(single account) login details? 
So any user can use dropbox directly without login popup.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what you're trying to do?  Why just one dropbox account?  I doubt DB would let you do this.

Comment: more or less a dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014001/allow-dropbox-api-to-access-my-account-on-users-device/15030046

Comment: I want to use the dropbox as server so any user can upload & download the files to the single account without interact to dropbox login.Thanks to all for replys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to set access user access token pair manually.

```
     AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
     AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys, ACCESS_TYPE);
     if (mDBApi == null) {
        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

//  mDBApi.getSession().startAuthentication(Main.this);  //kicks off the web-based authentication
      //you'll have to use the web-based authentication UI one-time to get the ######### values
        String token_key="#########";  
        String token_seceret="#########";
        AccessTokenPair tokens=new AccessTokenPair(token_key,token_seceret);
        mDBApi.getSession().setAccessTokenPair(tokens);     
  //  boolean v=mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful(); 
    }
```

First time i run application in debug mode with break point i get the token key and token secret of by entering valid log in detail.and saved(noted) that credential and after that i set them manually as above code then can be log in successfully.

Comment: How would you get token_key and token_secret manually without launching the dropbox authentication screen?

Comment: You *will* have to launch the authentication screen, but *just once*.  Then turn it off and set the token key pair manually as shown above.

Comment: But is it possible to hard code credentials in source so authentication screen doesn't show even once.. If I want to show demo to 100 users they would need to type user/pass for that demo and I want to avoid that.. :S

Comment: @DhiliphSoundher,After login you can get the key and token but need to run application in debug mode put the break point where you want to get in variables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Have a look at their example app DBRoulette.

Comment: I have solve this issue by setting the user access token pair manually. and also working fine for other user without login.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the project from the below link name as **DBRoulette**

> https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core

And create an app in https://www.dropbox.com/developers and get the api key and secret and add this both in **DBRoulette.java** and in **AndroidManifest.xml** ...it works..

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate() write

```
AppKeyPair pair = new AppKeyPair(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET);
    session = new AndroidAuthSession(pair, AccessType.APP_FOLDER);
    dropbox = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(DROPBOX_NAME, 0);
    String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY, null);
    String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET, null);
    if (key != null && secret != null) {
        Log.d("key secret", key + "    " + secret);
        AccessTokenPair token = new AccessTokenPair(key, secret);
        dropbox.getSession().setAccessTokenPair(token);
    }
    if (key == null && secret == null)
            dropbox.getSession().startAuthentication(DropboxActivity.this);
```

And in onResume() write

```
if (dropbox.getSession().isLinked()) {
        try {
            loggedIn(true);
            doAction();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error during Dropbox authentication",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        } else if (dropbox.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                session.finishAuthentication();
                TokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(DROPBOX_NAME, 0);
                Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString(ACCESS_KEY, tokens.key);
                editor.putString(ACCESS_SECRET, tokens.secret);
                editor.commit();

                loggedIn(true);
                doAction();

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error during Dropbox authentication",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

It worked fine for me