# Send files directly to my Dropbox space through my android app, without asking the user to log in

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have developed a android application through which user can send their files to my server. here i want to use drop-box to receive files directly to it. when the user is sending files, it should directly reach my drop-box space. i have developed a test app, by referencing the drop-box API, but it asks me every-time to log in to drop-box. i'm planing to put my app in Google play store, there i cannot go to every user those who download my app, and log in to my drop-box account.

In Short:
 How can i make my users to send files directly to my drop-box space, without asking the user to log in to drop-box.

Comment: You can't unless you want your users to use your own credentials to login in which case you can use your own account instead to upload the files.

Comment: i don't understand what you are saying. can you please tell me more clearly? @user3718908

Comment: To use dropbox you must login, there is no way around that. Now it is either your users login to their own accounts using their own credentials or you simply pass your own credentials to the api whenever a user wants to do an upload. So that the users use your account to do the uploads..

Comment: but here i will be launching my app to Google play store, the person will be downloading from all around India. there i  cannot go to every user and give my credentials. Moreover my app will be used by the farmers, they don't know to log in to drop-box and all! is there anyway that i can programatically log in to my drop-box account? please help...

Comment: You can set that from your code behind or you make your application pull the authentication credentials from your server.

Comment: can you tell me how can i do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72677/discussion-between-ranjithstar256-and-user3718908).

Comment: For anyone else reading this, this is possible but very much not recommended. There's a similar question, albeit for iOS, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834922/auto-login-dropbox-account-on-core-api-without-login-prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully implemented this! Thanks to @Greg ! :)

Solution is here!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15758793/2811343

Sharing it as it may be useful for someone in future.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: Thanks @JaimeGómez i have already up voted the Greg comment :) ;) Actually i acknowledged that i got solution for my question.