# Create an app with Dropbox integration

Tags: android, dropbox

Is it possible to create an android app with Dropbox integration that allows multiple user to upload images in one Dropbox account.

I am new to android programming, please help.

Comment: AFAIK Dropbox doesn't allow this

Comment: Thanks sir, sir what if I create a server website is it possible to do that? the app will send the images into the server then send images to my dropbox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send files directly to my Dropbox space through my android app, without asking the user to log in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959955/send-files-directly-to-my-dropbox-space-through-my-android-app-without-asking-t)