# Using your own Dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Most of the examples of Dropbox Core API assume you want to download or upload a file to current users DB account. But I would like to download a file and file info from my DB account. How can I do that? I already have the app key and secret.

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking here. Are you asking if you want to change the current logged in users to dropbox? You can check who is logged in using the AndroidAuthSession Class.

Comment: I want to download file from my DB account, not from current user that is using the phone.

Comment: You mean u want every person who uses your app to download files from your account?

Comment: Essentially the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15014001/1305693