# Can I authenticate to Dropbox API programmatically?

Tags: android, oauth, dropbox-api

I'm developing android app, using the Dropbox API on Android. The API has a link activity to link an account with the app.

I have the app key and app secret and the Dropbox account and the password, and I need to put this info in the code programmatically.

**What I don't want** is this login/link activity, assuming I have a Dropbox account and password and I want to link/authenticate programmatically with this particular account without demanding the user to link or login or input any account or password.

Can I do that?

Comment: Why is it so important? I mean, the link is only made one time, then the app has access to Dropbox until uninstalled

Comment: @cYrixmorten i want all the users who use this app to not know the account nor the password i'm linking them to , cuz im using 1 account to store some infos that i dont want the user to use the account and access on the regular dropbox  website and see the files. like database etc ..

Comment: Then I would advise you to use Parse.com or similar instead.

Comment: @cYrixmorten could you explain more maybe a link or tutorial ? sorry im note familiar with Parse.com

Comment: Try and go to their website, they have plenty of tutorials and documentation :-)

Comment: The original question regarding Dropbox is basically a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014001/allow-dropbox-api-to-access-my-account-on-users-device (and others)

Comment: Parse was good untill it died last week. Jan 2016)

Comment: @UtsavGupta really , it did ?

Comment: @mhdjazmati Yup, They are winding within 6  months and calling it off totally within a year. I see some conspiracy there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i found actually dropbox offered what i want to do .

now dropbox will let you generate public access token and use it inside your code

so yes , there is a way to allow permanent access to dropbox API. we need to generate access token from the application settings(dropbox console) and use it. Here is what dropbox says:

> By generating an access token, you will be able to make API calls for
>   your own account without going through the authorization flow. To
>   obtain access tokens for other users, use the standard OAuth flow.

in code words :

```
AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

    private AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
        AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TOKEN);
        // I guess then you just have to instantiate a DropboxAPI object and you're good to go without the startAuthentication()... endAuthentication() etc.
        return session;
    }
```

and here we go just use the mApi to do whatever you want