# How to download files from server to a plugin's internal storage directory

Tags: java, android, apk, android-internal-storage, dexclassloader

I have an app called **MyNiceApp** installed in the internal storage `/data/app/com.myniceapp.root_pkg`.

**QUESTIONS 1**

> Is it possible to programatically download files into `/data/app/com.myniceapp.root_pkg`

**QUESTIONS 2**

MyNiceApp is the core app that only contains the main core view that is to be populated by views generated by plugins that a user will download in APK format from my server as wishes.

> Is it possible to download these plugin APKs from a personal server into this directory (`/data/app/com.myniceapp.root_pkg`) and launch the views into the main core view?

I'm thinking it would be better organized if I had a folder created under /data/app/com.myniceapp.root_pkg/plugins, then have DexClassLoader crawl /data/app/com.myniceapp.root_pkg/plugins for downloaded plugins, then I could call my Class implementations, and dynamically load the plugin views to the core view at runtime.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1: 
[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714761/download-a-file-programmatically-on-android)
 is a sample (SOF question) for downloading.
 If u would like write to an internal directory you can use this:
 `File myDir = context.getDir("MyInternalDirectory", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` 
That will create a directory in your package folder (comment: the 'context' is not needed if you are in the main thread).

Answer 2:

Working on it....

I hope this will help.