# How to download Tik Tok Video from android webview in android?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-download-manager

I want to load Tik tok url ***https://www.tiktok.com/en/trending*** in android webview, and when i click on video it should download that video using Android download manager. How Can i detect the downloading url of the video and how can i download it from that android webview. As we know we can download video from Facebook like in the below link, I want to download Tik Tok Video from that webview
[Downlading video from facebook using android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714761/download-a-file-programmatically-on-android)

My code is:

```
 webView.loadUrl(""+getString(R.string.URL));
```