# How to open built-in download manager in android

Tags: android, android-studio, download-manager

Hy guys can u please tell me how can I open the default download manager of my android device on the button click in android. I don't know what can I do on button click please suggest.

```
 case R.id.download1:
            break;
```

Comment: you want to download a file with default download manager? or just open download manager  to see all downloaded files?

Comment: to download a file with download manager see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9033224/2425851

Answer (score 0):

to open download manager add this

```
startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
```

Comment: Bro, I did this but it opens the download folder, not mobile default download manage from where user can pause or resume their downloading.

Answer (score 0):

To open the download manager or enable or disable the notifications of download manager in the mobile phone. Click on settings then apps then click on the sort button icon which is shown in the horizontal line in your apps. Enable show system apps. Now the download manager app will be shown in the list. Open the download manager app and go to notifications click on notification categories and enable or disable as required.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35042877)